# Giving Your Control DataField and DataSource Properties in VB6 (ActiveX Control)

Tags: vb6, controls, activex

How do I add the `DataSource` and `DataField` properties to my ActiveX control?

My UserControl:

[image]
<sub>(source: [picofile.com](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8138879442/1.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [picofile.com](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8138880934/2.png))</sub>

Comment: this is not ms-access. Access does not use vba userforms. Also what/where is your question?

Answer (score 1):

From [Creating An ActiveX Control That Is A Data Source](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson13/p31.html):

1. Create a new ActiveX control project.
2. Set a reference in the project to the appropriate data library
   through the Project, References menu dialog box.
3. ***Set the UserControl's DataSourceBehavior property to 1-vbDataSource.***
4. Create property procedures for custom properties that programmers
   will use to manipulate the data source control's connection to data.
   Typically, you'll implement String properties such as ConnectString
   (connection string to initialize a Connection object) and
   RecordSource (string to hold the query to initialize the data in the
   recordset). Create private variables to hold the values of each of
   the properties. Create private constants to hold their initial
   default values. Program the InitProperties, ReadProperties, and
   WriteProperties event procedures to persist these properties.
5. If you want to expose the control's Recordset for other programmers
   to manipulate, then you should create a custom property name,
   RecordSet. Its type will be the appropriate Recordset type that you
   plan to program for your control. You may choose to make it
   read-only, in which case you only need to give it a Property Get
   procedure. Declare a private object variable to hold its value using
   WithEvents (this exposes the event procedures to other programmers).
6. Declare a Private variable of the appropriate connection type that
   you plan to program for your control. It will not correspond to a
   custom property, but it's necessary in order to host the Recordset.
7. Code the InitProperties, ReadProperties, and WriteProperties events
   to properly manage and persist the values of the properties created
   in the previous steps.
8. Program the UserControl's GetDataMember event procedure to
   initialize a recordset and return it in the second parameter. You
   will derive the Recordset either from information contained in
   custom Private variables or from hard-coded information in the
   GetDataMember event procedure itself (see the previous section for
   an example). You should perform some errortrapping to ensure that
   you do indeed have a valid connection.
9. Put code in the UserControl's Terminate event that will gracefully
   close the data connection.
10. If you want to allow users to navigate data by directly
     manipulating your UserControl, then put the appropriate user
     interface on your UserControl along with the code to navigate the
     Recordset variable.
11. Your new ActiveX control should now be ready to test as a
     DataSource:Add a standard EXE project to the Project Group. Now,
     making sure you've closed the designer for the UserControl, add an
     instance of your new control to the standard EXE's form.
12. Manipulate any necessary custom properties (such as ConnectString
     or RecordSource) that you may have put in your custom control.
13. Put one or more bindable controls in the test project and set their
     DataSource property to point to the instance of your Data Source
     Control. Set their DataField properties to point to fields from the
     exposed Recordset.

Comment: thanks. i do not speak english. Please write the code for my example. My text box is that it has this property.

Comment: @HamidrezaMollaebrahimi: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.  My answer summarizes what you need to do. The link at the top actually has some useful code.  See if translate.google.com can help you with translation.

Comment: This process is in the book (pdf).
Please write you a small example and give me the link of the project. Sorry

Comment: This answer is also not a "straight code" sample. There are a lot of conditionals and things that depend on your existing code and what you want to expose, as well as properties that are set at design time.